# Нужна помощь в решении задачи по SQL (с применением оператора LIKE)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

Данные для задания:

```sql
create table Inventory
(ID int identity (1,1) not null primary key,
 InventoryCode varchar (10) not null,
 [Description] varchar (200) not null);
 
 INSERT INTO Inventory
 (InventoryCode,[Description])
 VALUES 
 ('IN_345678','office radiotelephone'),
 ('IN_34578','office table'),
 ('INARMCHAIR','office armchair'),
 ('INPHONE','office phone'),
 ('IN34578','office chair'),
 ('IN_34578','notebook'),
 ('IN_34578','display')
```

Что необходимо найти:

For each of those queries you can use only one operator LIKE:

1. a query that returns only those InventoryCodes that don't contain digits with their Descriptions
2. a query that returns only those InventoryCodes that don't contain symbols '_' with their Descriptions

Для каждого из этих запросов вы можете использовать только один оператор LIKE:

1. запрос, который возвращает только те InventoryCodes, которые не содержат цифр с их описаниями
2. запрос, который возвращает только те InventoryCodes, которые не содержат символов '_' с их описаниями.

Мой ответ был такой:

```sql
SELECT InventoryCode
FROM Inventory
WHERE InventoryCode NOT LIKE '%[^A-z]%';

SELECT InventoryCode
FROM Inventory
WHERE InventoryCode NOT LIKE 'IN\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Но они были оценены как неверные. Подскажите пожалуйста где моя ошибка?

Comment: `LIKE` не понимает регулярных выражений

Comment: Я так понимаю что использовать их все же можно. Предикат LIKE в его стандартной редакции не поддерживает регулярных выражений, хотя ряд реализаций (в частности, Oracle) допускает их использование, расширяя возможности стандарта.

В SQL Server 2005/2008 использование регулярных выражений возможно через CLR, т.е. посредством языков Visual Studio, которые могут использоваться для написания хранимых процедур и функций.

Comment: Однако в Transact-SQL, помимо стандартных символов-шаблонов ("%" и "_"), существует еще пара символов, которые делают этот предикат LIKE более гибким инструментом. Этими символами являются:

[ ] - одиночный символ из набора символов (например, [zxy]) или диапазона ([a-z]), указанных в квадратных скобках. При этом можно перечислить сразу несколько диапазонов (например, [0-9a-z]);
^ - который в сочетании с квадратными скобками исключает из поискового образца символы из набора или диапазона.

Comment: Это из учебника Сергея Моисеенко. А как можно мои запросы изменить чтобы получить правильный ответ?

Comment: Вот сам комментарий к моим решениям: Wrong. Query is supposed to return records without digits. In fact, it returns rows that has only letters (range from A to z). Second query for underscore is also with flaw.

Comment: Судя по тексту задания, условия надо накладывать на поле Description

Comment: так в этом поле только текст содержится. Откуда тогда цифры отрезать?))

Answer (score 1):

Первое задание требует исключить цифры, авторы же исключает все не буквы, в том числе и знак подчеркивания, который явно присутствует в примерах. А нужно исключить только цифры:

```
SELECT InventoryCode, Descriptions
FROM Inventory
WHERE InventoryCode NOT LIKE '%[0123456789]%';
```

Второе задание требует исключить подчеркивание, а не коды, начинающиеся с `IN_`.

```
SELECT InventoryCode, Descriptions
FROM Inventory
WHERE InventoryCode NOT LIKE '%~_%' ESCAPE '~';
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ну, я могу, конечно, скопипастить сюда описание оператора LIKE, но об этом не спрашивали. Каков вопрос, таков ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: В первом решении остаются те строки, которые содержат только буквы, то есть цифры не отрезаются от IN_. А я так понимаю что ответ должен быть IN_
IN_
INARMCHAIR
INPHONE
IN
IN_
IN_

Comment: А выводятся только строки INARMCHAIR  и  INPHONE